# Laravel Login Controller - Direct to Admin or User Routes

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes, admin

I have a Laravel8 Project where I am doing everything from scratch so i can learn the system (newbie) - I have a LoginController with the code

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // Show Login Page
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email'=> 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        if (!auth()->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'), $request->remember)) {
           return back()->with('status', 'Invalid Login Details' );
        }

        return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
    }
```

I have the roles tables and pivot table set up but not sure how to amend the return `redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');` to the correct code so depending if the user is an admin or a standard user it uses the correct route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give simple condition after login attempt success like below.

```
if (auth()->user()->role == 'admin') {
    return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
}
return redirect()->route('user.dashboard');
```

As per your described question, you have a different table for assign roles to the user. So you have to create relation with roles table to identifies the role of the user.

Comment: If you are doing it from scratch and want to learn something new, I suggest going with multi guard authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure to import the `Auth` `facade` at the top of the class. Next, let's check out the `attempt` method:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
...


public function store(Request $request) {
    // ... 

    if (!auth()->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'), $request->remember)) {
        return back()->with('status', 'Invalid Login Details' );
    }

    // Redirect to admin dashboard
    return redirect()->intended('route.dashboard');
}
```

For more details read the Docs [Manually Authenticating Users](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#authenticating-users)